# Hibernate code checks if session is closed before commiting txn but then complains session is closed

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate (with H2 database), sometimes if a task takes too long I cancel it so the session associate with the task becomes invalid. I have a method typically used in finally blocks and this ensure txn is committed and session closed but only if sessions till open, and not rolled back.

```
public static void commitAndClose(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        if (session!=null && session.isOpen() && !session.getTransaction().wasRolledBack())
        {
            if(session.getTransaction().isActive())
            {
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         Errors.addError(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (session!=null && session.isOpen())
        {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet for some reason it is trying to commit the txn and then complains it was closed, even though the closed check immediately beforehand was okay.

Is this just a timing issue ?

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3238)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
        at com.jthink.songkong.util.SessionUtil.commitAndClose(SessionUtil.java:32)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.doTask(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:448)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.java:469)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:83)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:37)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-199]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:170)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1568)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1547)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:347)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:546)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, it looks like the app is trying to commit something after you closed the session, hence the error.
Can you post the code where you cancel the task please ?

Comment: Is this code run from the same thread?

Comment: A better practice would be to use `@Transactional` and let hibernate worry about transaction handling

Comment: The code is run using Executors with a timeout, and if a task takes too long then the Executor is cancelled. So yes it is trying to commit after closed session but the point is that the checks to see if session is closed before trying to commit so why doesnt that check prevent it from trying to commit ?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer in the long run Im going to move away from Hibernate and back to SQL formy project it is giving few benefits and a number of problems.